# How to install and configure Rocket.chat using snap?

Tags: server

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit Desktop. I have found out this article: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/09/22/rocket-chat-a-new-snap-is-landing-on-your-nextcloud-box-and-beyond/ about hot to install Rocket.chat using snap and how to start working with it. The article states:

**On most modern Intel servers or VPSes, `snap install rocketchat.server` takes only about 30 seconds. The server is ready to handle hundreds of users immediately, available at URL`http://<server address>:3000`.**

I have figured out that actual package name is: rocketchat-server, so correct command is: `snap install rocketchat-server` Installation worked fine, no errors were found.

But now other part of above statement about URL address. In the same machine In Firefox 48 browser I typed in address: http://192.168.100.15:3000  (this is my IP address, checked with ifconfig command) but I get error "Unable to connect". I tried "netstat -antop" and I can see any "rocket chat" server running.

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I don't really have a lot of time, I would just like to test if this server has functionalities appropriate for our company needs or not. Proper configuration will come later when we decide if product meets our needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the same machine you installed rocketchat, the address is actually https://localhost:3000. You'll have access to the server for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, but try this:

- Open this: https://192.168.100.15:3000
- And then open this: http://192.168.100.15:3000

It will work :/